# I am creating the controller in asp dot net core but Giving Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, developer-tools

I am try to create the controller in asp.net core mvc web appication in visual studio V2019.
But while creating the controller it gives an error deps.json file does not exist.

[image]

I search all the files from my project but didn't get it

Comment: Thank you sir. It's working in my case.

Comment: You could [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) by right click on the grey check box beside your question. It would be helpful for another community member

Answer (score 2):

Seems your compiler doesn't get your project reference accordingly.

*Solution:*

> `Delete` your `bin` and try `rebuild` project your required file will be regenerated.

See the screen shot :

[image]

Hope that would help.